# "とした" in context of adjective/object

Tags: grammar

I'm working through a translation for practice and in order to translate "spacious pockets" my two options are :

> 広々ポケット

or

> 広々としたポケット

I don't get where "とした" comes from and if it's necessary in that context. The examples I've found around the internet seem to relate to other instances, so I don't really get this one. Thanks so much in advance!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of (と)した in やんわりとした暖房](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/74965/meaning-of-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f-in-%e3%82%84%e3%82%93%e3%82%8f%e3%82%8a%e3%81%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e6%9a%96%e6%88%bf)

Comment: Also, 広々is being used as an adverb here, not an adjective. 広々ポケット is not grammatically sound.

Comment: It deeply depends on the context  since both sounds like strange collocation.広々（とした）does not connect ポケット because ポケット is small.

Answer (score 1):

広々としたポケット is an ordinary noun phrase with an adnominal clause: "pocket which presents itself spaciously" or "spacious pocket". On the other hand, 広々ポケット is a nonce compound made of an adverb and a noun. The 広々 here is not modifying ポケット with the right capacity of adverb or adjective (adverb cannot modify noun on its own), but just two words crudely put together to mean something creative. In this sense, it certainly can be translated as "spacious pocket", but also as "roominess pocket", "a 'relax' pocket" or even "plen-T-pocket" and such. As you may notice, it has quite an affinity for advertisement rhetoric.

- オレオレ詐欺 lit. "me!-me! scam" → grandparents scam
- シャカシャカポテト lit. "shake-shake potato" → (McDonald's) mix-your-own seasoned fries
- 簡単操作 lit. "operate-easy" → (Windows') Ease of Access

Somewhat related:

- [Why isn't 日本料理 written as 日本の料理?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27485/7810)
- [-的 adjectives modifying nouns without な](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21150/7810)
- [the omission of an implied “の” creates the appearance of a 四字熟語?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19365/7810)