# Onomatopoeia + と + した = Adjective?

Tags: particle-と, adjectives

むっちりとした太股 was translated as “plump thighs”. Can I make an onomatopoeia into an adjective by adding とした?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/74972/9831

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of (と)した in やんわりとした暖房](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/74965/meaning-of-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f-in-%e3%82%84%e3%82%93%e3%82%8f%e3%82%8a%e3%81%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e6%9a%96%e6%88%bf). とした works well with most "visual trait" type onomatopoeias, aka 擬態語/mimesis.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no.

In most monolingual dictionaries, those onomatopoeias are noted explicitly as such.

> [むっちり](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%80%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1%E3%82%8A-641962)
>
> 1 〘副〙 **(多く「と」を伴って用いる)**
> ① 肌に張りがあって肉付きのよいさまを表わす語

---

Onomatopoeias describing sounds can rarely be used with とした - ザーザー(rain), しとしと(rain)、ビュービュー(wind) won't work with と(した).

Those describing a state mostly work with とした - ニコニコ(smile), つるつる(polished or slippery). But exceptions are not rare: カチカチとした (hard) doesn't work, it should be カチカチの to modify a noun.